# Include Snippet programatically on app install

Tags: shopify

I have an app that I am using on Shopify store. When I install it i have used assets api to create a snippet file. Everything works fine.
What I am trying to achieve is that whenever user install my application the app snippet which is created should be included automatically on product-template.liquid file on a desirable place (e.g above add to cart button).
What i have done is I have used again assets api to get the page data and I am trying to place my code that will include that snippet but I am not sure how to specify position where to add that code.

Comment: you need to specify it into code, but due to a lot of themes and different structures. you need to mention the steps into documentation or prepare a video, add it, or offer the install service after APP install.

Comment: Solution:  I did it by getting page as a string via assets Api and then by getting position i updated it with my line of code

Comment: sure, but might be documentation and help to install the APP also build the trust into the developer, and might be some cases where the theme structures are totally different. you need to go with manual installation as well.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:  I did it by getting page as a string via assets Api and then by getting position i updated it with my line of code